# BASH option overrides $2 Variable in Rename command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make this program work and I can't. The $2 variable that I want to use inside the Rename command takes the content assigned by the Select Opt. Is there any way to use $1, $2 variables in a Rename command while inside a Select Opt structure?

```
OPTIONS="\"Quit\" \"Replace\""
echo $OPTIONS
eval set $OPTIONS

select opt in "$@"; do
    if [ "$opt" = "Quit" ]; then
       echo done
       exit
    elif [ "$opt" = "Replace" ]; then
       ls
       echo "old pattern"
       read OLD
       echo "new one"
       read NEW
       rename -n "s/($OLD)(.*)/$NEW$2/" *.jpg
```

The final result in

```
rename -n "s/($OLD)(.*)/$NEW$2/" *.jpg
```

is $NEW and the string "Replace" instead of the (.*) part.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** I have modified the code according to skmrx suggestions. Now the results are different and $1, $2 are empty. The Rename command is not using them and the code still doesn't work.

```
OPTIONS=("Quit" "Replace")
echo "${OPTIONS[@]}"

select opt in "${OPTIONS[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$opt" = "Quit" ]]; then
           echo done
           exit
    elif [[ "$opt" = "Replace" ]]; then
       ls
       echo "old pattern"
       read OLD
       echo "new one"
       read NEW
       rename -n "s/($OLD)(.*)/$NEW$2/" *.jpg
    else
       clear
       echo bad option
    fi
done
```

The instruction

```
rename -n "s/($OLD)(.*)/$NEW$2/" *.jpg
```

Executes with just the content of the $NEW variable and $2 remains empty with no text.

Answer (score 0):

In short, `eval set $OPTIONS` is overriding your `$1` and `$2`. Try `echo`ing them in the next line.

Now, here are some ways in which you can improve the script and make it less error prone:

1. Make `OPTIONS` an array: `OPTIONS=("Quit" "Replace")`. This will allow you to keep spaces in the option names without bothering to escape the double quotes. To echo the options, you can use `echo "${OPTIONS[@]}"`.
2. There's no need to `eval set`. That just causes problems by overwriting the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc.
3. Use `"${OPTIONS[@]}"` instead of `"$@"` in `select` - this becomes necessary since `set` will no longer be used.
4. Use `[[..]]` instead of `[..]`. There's less of a chance of making mistakes in the first case.